# {... } spread operator not working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ide, atom-editor

I'm a newbie at JS doing an online course. I'm using the Atom developer environment with the *script* package to run my code.

Despite copying exactly what the instructor wrote, there is a consistent error which says "unexpected token" at **{** **.**..

I've tried creating a .jshintrc document to upgrade to ES9, but this didn't fix the problem.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Sarah',
  age: 20,
  greet() {
    console.log('Hi, I am ' + this.name);
  }
};

const copiedPerson = { ...person };
console.log(copiedPerson);
```

I expect the output to be a copy of the "person" variable, but there's only the "unexpected token" error. What could be wrong and what could I do to fix it?

Comment: It runs just fine here

Comment: The syntax looks fine. If that's your code verbatim, it sounds like it's a problem with the linter. I'd highly recommend ESLint instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried using fast-eslint because eslint is depreciated currently. Fast eslint showed me 3 errors in this code and didn't change the error message. The teacher of my course thinks its a problem with the IDE. Do you know anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: The `script` packages runs your code in whatever version of Node you have installed on your computer. Your code works fine in Node v10 (and later versions)